# The write command wont function when put into my code

Tags: python

I'm making an adventure game, and at the end I want it to print if the user to answer if they liked the game and if they did I want it to write the answer in a `.txt` file. As of now, I want it to open a `.txt` file and write anything at all and it won't. It works on its own but when put into my program it won't execute.

I've tried moving its position, I've tried if statements and while loops and the effects have been nothing.

```
import sys


def main():
    play_again = True
    first_choice = True
    fleft_choice = False
    fright_choice = False
    print_thing = True
    while play_again:
        print('Welome to my adventure game, would you like to play?')

        answer = input()
        answer = answer.lower()
        if answer == 'yes' or answer == 'y':
            print('Fantastic, off we go')
        elif answer == 'no' or answer == 'n':
            print('Its your choice')
            break
        else:
            print('invalid input')
            continue

        while first_choice:
            print('You come up to a fork in the road. To the left, you hear a battle raging. To the right is winding '
                  'path that leads to a cave.')

            answer1 = input('which do you choose')
            if answer1 == "left":
                print('you join the fight')
                play_again = False
                first_choice = False
                fleft_choice = True

            elif answer1 == 'right':
                print('you light a tourch and enter the cave')
                play_again = False
                first_choice = False
                fright_choice = True
            else:
                print('invalid input')
                continue

            while fleft_choice:
                print('something happens in battle')
                fleft_choice = False

            while fright_choice:
                print('something is in the cave')
                fright_choice = False

    print('Did you enjoy your adventure?')
    yesfile = open("testfile.txt", "w")
    yesfile.write('lorem ipsum')
    yesfile.close()

    print('would you like to play again?')
    end_answer = input()
    if end_answer == "yes" or end_answer == "y":
        main()
    if end_answer == 'no' or end_answer == 'n':
        sys.exit()


main()
```

What I'm trying to figure out is why the write function will work on its own but when it's implemented it just seems to be skipped.

Comment: Does the program print the `Did you enjoy your adventure?` message?  If so, then it must also create the file, as it's the very next line of code.  Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the file?  It will be in the current directory, which is not necessarily the same directory as the game program.

Comment: Also, why is `def main():` indented by twelve spaces?

Comment: it prints it, it also runs the next line. and in pycharm it opens a txt file under my scratch files. It just seems to be skipping this part of the code entirely.

Comment: Where are you looking for the file?

Comment: If you print the output of `os.getcwd()`, that should tell you what directory the file is in.

Comment: my ide opens it for me. Im very new at this and teaching myself so i know i look like an idiot

Comment: Can confirm that it shows up for me, in the same directory where I ran a python file containing your code without ay changes. It showed up after the code terminated execution.

Comment: that's quite odd. Thanks for the response @ABusyProgrammer

Comment: @joshbailey So PyCharm opens the `.txt` file, but it is blank?

Comment: When I run the writing section of the code in a new window it runs just fine and does exactly what its supposed to do. When I put it into the program above it is completely ignored. @ABusyProgrammer

Comment: @joshbailey You can try `yesfile.flush()`, although `yesfile.close()` already does that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is not in infinite loop with all those while loops in the middle of function?
This is most obvious reason that comes to my mind.

Also, when using files it is advised to use this type syntax:

```
content = "test"
with open("file.txt", 'w', encoding="UTF8") as fp:
    fp.write(content)
```

This way you will never forget to save file, but yours should works as well.

Comment: I doubled checked to make sure and it wasn't in any loop. I also copied yours in to test it out and see if it fixed it. I had no luck. The syntax is clearly correct. Where im using pycharm it seems to not like actually doing what its supposed to do lol. Someone else copied and ran my code to check and said that it worked just fine for them. Im very clueless at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enclosing your file opening, writing and closing operations inside a `try-catch` block. The error this returns to you can determine what the issue is:

```py
try:
    yesfile = open(testfile.txt, "w")
    yesfile.write(output)
    yesfile.close()

except IOError as (number, description):
    print("Error({0}): {1}".format(number, description))
```